# Deploy WPF Application with SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, deployment, publish

How do I get a WPF application, with A SQLIte database, on another PC? When running the code on the machine on which the app has been developed, there is no problem. But I cannot get the program to run on another PC.

I have been searching the internet for days. All literature are either vague or does not show the process from A to Z. Following the dozens of instructions on the net gives me results that either 1) Does not include the Database when the application gets installed on another pc, or 2 crashes the program. And the Microsoft literature talks alot but explains nothing.

How does the app knows in which folder to find the Sqlite database?
How does the app knows it must interact with the database?

What should the code look like to work on the other pc? What should the XAML look like to work on the other PC? And, PLEASE, in which classes or windows should they be?

By now I now in detail how to do all of the above for my local PC. I cannot get the app to run on another PC

Comment: You asked for a lot of question ! Seems you do not understand what you have done... ? at minima, provide us with an exception ? or a sample code :-(

Comment: You should deploy a local database to appdatalocal. Depends on your installer how you'd specify that. But you can probably google it once you know appdata is part of your search. You can then find the specific folder to build your connection string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes,yes,yes!!!!

I found the solution! In the App.config page, the connectionstring must be as follows:

">" 
">"  "connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalaryAndWageApp.csdl|res://*/SalaryAndWag">"eApp.ssdl|res://*/SalaryAndWageApp.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provid">"er connection string='data ">"source="|DataDirectory|\WageAndSalaryApp.db"'" ">"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

With the "|DataDirectory|\WageAndSalaryApp." working the magic